# Error: The method object <Constructor>(ApexPages.StandardController) is referenced by Vf Page (VF_FAS_RecordType)

Tags: controller

Can someone tell me why am I getting the above error for my controller

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Revenue_Reports__c" extensions="FAS_intercontroller" action="!FAS_intercontrollermethod">
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class FAS_intercontroller {

public Revenue_Reports__c R1;

public void FAS_intercontrollermethod (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
this.R1 = (Revenue_Reports__c)controller.getRecord();

}

 public PageReference FASpageRedirect() {
    if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') == '01I230000008cX9'){
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/RevenueReports_FAS_VfPge');
        return pageRef;
    }
        else if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccountId') == null){
         PageReference pageRef2 = new PageReference('https://cs28.salesforce.com/a4T/o');
         return pageRef2;
     }
         return null;
       }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action method is different from constructor .

Your constructor will run once the page is loaded and hence you need not specify an action on your apex:page tag

The correct controller code would look like

```
public with sharing class FAS_intercontroller {

 public Revenue_Reports__c R1;

 public FAS_intercontrollermethod (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.R1 = (Revenue_Reports__c)controller.getRecord();
}

 public PageReference FASpageRedirect() {
     if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') == '01I230000008cX9'){
       PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/RevenueReports_FAS_VfPge');
       return pageRef;
   }
    else if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccountId') == null){
        PageReference pageRef2 = new  PageReference('https://cs28.salesforce.com/a4T/o');
         return pageRef2;
       }
         return null;
     }
}
```

The visualforce code

```
  <apex:page standardController="Revenue_Reports__c" extensions="FAS_intercontroller"/>
```

Also i noticed couple of things

1.Harcoded RecordtypeIds .Please do not harcode and use developer name instead as it changes across instances

2.Hardcoded URLS - Please avoid same as you do not want to be changing this in PROD once code is deployed to other orgs .